# Why the terminal message shows, "nothing to commit" when the message above reads, "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit."?

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface, git-bash

Why the terminal message shows, "nothing to commit" when the message above reads, "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit."?

[image]

Comment: There are not any pending changes *locally* (nothing to commit). Being "ahead" means you have local commits that are not pushed to origin (behind means there are remote changes you don't have locally). Those are two different aspects (local vs. remote).

Comment: You might consider reading [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) to learn more about Git and how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two messages are talking about 2 different things. The first (`Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.`) is telling you that you have made 1 commit to your local repository, but you have not yet pushed it (`get push`) to the remote repository.

The second message (`nothing to commit...`) is referring to your local directory.  You have not made any modification, additions, or deletions to the files there that have not been committed. So, there is nothing to commit.

Once you do make some changes and commit them locally then you'll get the message about your current branch being some number of commits ahead of the remote branch again.

Answer (score 0):

You already have commited your changes since you are ahead by 1 commit.
I suggest doing git status to see what uncommited changes you have.
What you are looking for is git push.

Answer (score 0):

The world of Git looks like this:

```
 your working tree (the files you see)
         |
         | nothing to commit to...
         V
    the index (where you git add to form a commit)
         |
         V
   actual commits (your local branch where commits go when you form them)
         |
         | you are one ahead of...
         V
   the remote repository (GitHub or whatever, an online copy of your repo)
```

There are two sets of relationships being described by `git status`: the working tree vs. the index, and your most recent commit locally vs the most recent commit back at GitHub or wherever the remote is. These do not contradict one another; in fact, they have nothing much to do with each other.

- *Nothing to commit* means your working tree matches the index. You cannot make a new commit because you have not changed anything.
- *Your branch is ahead* means you have already made some commits locally (one, in this case), and if you wanted GitHub or wherever the remote is to know about that, you would need to push.

No action is actually called for by either message. Just keep working if you like.